# setup.py to include dependencies from local lib

Tags: python, pip, project-management

I am about to make a distribution of a new package that people at my work should be able to install by `pip install my_package` given they receive the wheel locally. It should also install a list of *dependencies*. I am having trouble with the dependencies though.

I have all the dependencies locally (on the computer where I build the release) so I simply want to ship the package with these. But how do I do that automatically (assuming I have a list of the exact dependencies)?

I don't want to download dependencies from PyPi or somewhere similar since we have a strict firewall policy.

#### EDIT

I am thinking that I need to do something like

```
pip wheel --wheel-dir=lib/ -r requirements.txt
```

but it tries to fetch the requirements from url instead of getting it from the local lib folder. Suggestions?

Comment: You can use the option `--download-cache=/path/to/cache` with `pip install`, maybe it would also work with what you need.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy I don't want to install anything. I just want a wheel for each dependent package I am using for my project. So that I can ship the project with these wheels

Comment: Who said that you want to install anything? Read what I wrote carefully. Or I'll rather try to rephrase it in case I wrote it too complicated: `pip install` has the option `--download-cache`. Check if you can use such option also for `pip wheel`.

Answer (score 0):

[`pip wheel`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_wheel/) command has the [option `--index-url <url>`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_wheel/#cmdoption-i), which may be:

> Base URL of Python Package Index (default https://pypi.python.org/simple). This should point to a repository compliant with PEP 503 (the simple repository API) or a local directory laid out in the same format.

You can also check the [PyPI mirrors and caches](https://packaging.python.org/mirrors/) user guide article, if any of those solutions is suitable for you.

Comment: I found `pip download -r requirements.txt` to be useful.

Comment: So you download all dependencies locally and then what? How are your colleagues supposed to install it from there? BTW isn't `pip download` command without explicitly specified local directory downloading it from the PyPI server?